# Laravel Polymorphic One of Many Relationship with custom pivot?

Tags: laravel, polymorphism, relationship

In a Laravel 9 project, I am trying to define a polymorphic one of many relationship with a custom pivot model. However, `using` is not a method for a MorphOne relation:

```
return $this->morphOne(Associate::class, 'associables')
            ->using(Associable::class);

BadMethodCallException  Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphOne::using()
```

And just calling `latestOfMany` on a MorphOne with a custom pivot model throws a bad sql exception:

```
return $this->morphOne(Associate::class, 'associables')
            ->latestOfMany();

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'associates.associables_id' in 'field list' (SQL: select `associates`.* from `associates` inner join (select MAX(`associates`.`id`) as `id_aggregate`, `associates`.`associables_id`, `associates`.`associables_type` from `associates` where `associates`.`associables_type` = App\Models\Grant and `associates`.`associables_id` = 1 and `associates`.`associables_id` is not null group by `associates`.`associables_id`, `associates`.`associables_type`) as `latestOfMany` on `latestOfMany`.`id_aggregate` = `associates`.`id` and `latestOfMany`.`associables_type` = `associates`.`associables_type` and `latestOfMany`.`associables_id` = `associates`.`associables_id` where `associates`.`associables_type` = App\Models\Grant and `associates`.`associables_id` = 1 and `associates`.`associables_id` is not null).
```

My question is it possible to have a polymorphic one of many relationship with a custom pivot model? And if not supported, can I use `ofMany` to somehow join the custom pivot table?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are typing wrong. It should be:

```
//'associable' without 's'

return $this->morphOne(Associate::class, 'associable')->latestOfMany();
```

Comment: Can you check your associables table? If the table has associable_type and associable_id, it should be associable. It is based on the field name, not the table name.